# How to add slashes in the url? mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am looking to get a nice seo friendly url by dividing elements by slashes. I tried several .htaccess code but it didn't worked for me. I'm using get method to get the value and it's functioning properly. I want to change the url like I mentioned bellow. if anyone know how to change this, please help me to get through this.

FROM :

```
 http://localhost/new/index.php?page=1&per-page=9
```

TO:

```
 http://localhost/new/index/page/1/per-page/9
```

Comment: Show your attempts first.

Comment: @anubhava <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^new/index/?$ /index.php?page=$1&per-page=$2
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Root/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([^&]+)&per-page=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /new/index/page/%1/per-page/%2? [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^new/index/page/([^/]+)/per-page/([^/]+)/?$ /new/index.php?page=$1&per-page=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. the is ok. but the php function is not working. it says 'Object not found'